# How to merge N multi-lists into one big multi-list?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have `n` multi-lists. I want to merge them into one big multi-list.
Example:

```
   listA =  [[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]]
   listB =  [[10,20],[30,40],[60,70]]
```

output:

```
  listAB = [[1,2,10,20],[3,4,30,40],[6,7,60,70]]
```

This is the code I wrote which computes the above:

```
listAB,tmp = [],[]
for i in range(len(listA)):
    for j in range(len(listA[i])):
        tmp.append(listA[i][j])
        tmp.append(listB[i][j])
    listAB.append(tmp)
    tmp = []
```

This code only works when you have two list, and the sub-list have the same length. I want to merge multiple multi-lists which have different lengths of sub-lists. Is there some function in `itertools` which can do these?

For example:

```
   listA =  [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
   listB =  [[10,20],[30,40],[60,70]]
   listC =  [[4,4],[5,5],[6]]

   listABC = [[1,2,3,10,20,4,4],
              [3,4,5,30,40,5,5],
              [6,7,8,60,70,6]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zip` the lists together and use `itertools.chain` to concatenate the output tuples:

```
from itertools import chain

listABC = [list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in zip(listA, listB, listC)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 30, 40, 5, 5], [6, 7, 8, 60, 70, 6]]
```

Although directly appending the lists is simpler for 3 inputs, with this approach you can also pass an **arbitrary number of lists** using the star operator:

```
# this can also be a tuple or any iterable
list_of_lists = [listA, listB, listC, listD ... ]

[list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in zip(*list_of_lists)]
```

---

UPDATE: an alternative solution (*not recommended*) using `functools` instead of `itertools` (as per the discussion with `ReblochonMasque`):

```
from functools import reduce

[reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, i) for i in zip(listA, listB, listC)]
```

Answer (score 4):

For two sequences, you can add them in a list comprehension:

```
[a+b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

For more than two, @meowgoesthedog answer is appropriate.
If for some reasons, you cannot use `itertools`, you could maybe do like this:

```
def merge(seq1, seq2):
    return (a+b for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2))

def merge_all(s):
    res = merge(s[0], s[1])
    for sn in s[2:]:
        res = merge(res, sn)
    return list(res)

A =  [[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]]
B =  [[10,20],[30,40],[60,70]]
C =  [[4,4],[5,5],[6]]

seq = [A, B, C]
merge_all(seq)
```

Comment: Shorter alternative for a solution without `itertools`: `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, seq)` (although this does use `functools`).

Comment: Are you sure it is correct @meowgoesthedog ?
it outputs `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 7], [10, 20], [30, 40], [60, 70], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6]]
`

Comment: As an example, `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [list(range(5)), list(range(5))])` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` as expected, so it might be due a mistake elsewhere? Using `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, i)` instead of `list(chain.from_iterable(i))` works for my solution.

Comment: It is the input that is incorrect @meowgoesthedog; per OP's input, it should be `functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [[list(range(5))], [list(range(5))]])`, which of course gives an incorrect result.

Comment: I didn't mean calling `reduce` *directly* on the input list of lists - I'll update with an example in my answer @ReblochonMasque

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can merge multiple multi-lists which have different lengths of sub-lists just by some simple code w/o using any `itertools`:

```
listCom = []
for n in range(len(listA)):
    listCom.append(listA[n] + listB[n] + listC[n])
listCom
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5, 30, 40, 5, 5], [6, 7, 8, 60, 70, 6]]
```